# Cannot run pwmconfig (There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed)

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, fan, amdgpu, fancontrol

I’m trying to control the fan speed in my laptop (Huawei Matebook D14 2020. AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Vega GPU). I’ve installed lm_sensors, and run sudo sensors-detect. However, when I try to run sudo pwmconfig, I get this output:

```
# pwmconfig version 3.6.0
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/bin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

What can I do?

Comment: First you need to see if the system is exposing the fan controls at all. Try `cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon?/pwm1`, possibly with sudo, as well as `cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon?/pwm1_enable` and `cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon?/temp1_input`. If those produce output at all, it's a settings issue, where if it's just "No such file or directory." that's a missing driver/kernel module.

Comment: @PeterJ.Mello hi thanks for answer. only temp1_input shows output. the pwm1 and pwm1_enable files are not in the directory.